# Как обработать несколько элементов на Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
$('#block').change(function(){
    var data = $('#block').data('prop');
    FuncName(data);
});
```

С одним блоком всё работает, но на странице нужно сделать много таких элементов (свойство `prop` будет у всех разное). Как правильно сделать обработчик в этом случае, чтобы понять какой их них переключили? Ведь `id` у всех блоков должен быть разный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно искать множество элементов так: `#id1, .class1 > div, a[data-id~="42"]`.
А внутри обработчика работать с `this`:

```js
// Создаём строку вида "#block1, #block2" и т. д.
let idPool = Array(...Array(4)).map((_, i) => '#block' + ++i).toString();
// Обработчик, аргумент - элемент в жуквери-обёртке
const handler = e => console.info(`data-id: ${e.data('id')}, value: ${e.text()}`);

$(idPool).on('click', function(){
  // this - DOM-элемент, оборачиваем его в жуквери (если нужно, конечно)
  handler($(this));
});
```

```css
div[data-id]{
  padding: 5px;
  background: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='block1' data-id='42'>1</div>
<div id='block2' data-id='24'>2</div>
<div id='block3' data-id='22'>3</div>
<div id='block4' data-id='44'>4</div>
```

---

Хотя, конечно, правильнее множество однотипных объектов объединять классом.

Answer (score 1):

Меняем `id`, на `class`. Радуемся.

```
$('.block').change(function(){
    var data = $(this).data('prop');
    FuncName(data);
});
```

`$(this)` внутри обработчика указывает конкретно на **тот самый** объект, на котором произошло событие на данный момент.

---

```js
$('.block').on('keyup', function(){    
    var data = $(this).data('prop');
    FuncName(data);
});

function FuncName(data) {
  console.log('my data prop = ' + data);  
}
```

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-prop="1" class="block" value="1">
<input type="text" data-prop="2" class="block" value="2">
<input type="text" data-prop="3" class="block" value="3">
```

---

```js
$('.block').change(function() {
    var data = $(this).data('prop');
    FuncName(data);
});

function FuncName(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="myradio" data-prop="allot" value="allot"  checked="checked" class="block">Allot
<input type="radio" name="myradio" data-prop="transfer" value="transfer" class="block">Transfer
```